# Magento free shipping shopping cart price rule for guest and registered users for particular countries

Tags: magento-1.7, php

[image]I have created a shopping cart rule for "Free Shipping" for particular country users.

Its working only for the logged in users in the cart page, its showing "Invalid rule" for guest users in the cart page. Please any one help me please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible if you haven't enabled it for guest users. Have you selected `NOT LOGGED IN` in customer group while creating promotional rule?

Please check the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

The best possible thing i'll suggest is, you should remove the coupon code for free shippping. so whenever the customer buys from website and enters his/her shipping address automatically the free shipping will be applied for them.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes, I have already selected "Not Logged In" option in the customer group.

Comment: are there any other rules created for promotion ?

Comment: Yes, but already I have checked by disabling other promotion rules, its not helped me :-(

Comment: Okay could you please paste the screenshot of your promotional rule?

Comment: Please check the screen short.. I have updated my question

Comment: This condition seems true.. check my anwer and verify if that is what you have done?

Comment: I did same like your screen, please check "Samir Shaban" answer, thats the issue am getting :-(

Comment: is it compulsory for you to use coupon code? The best solution will be not to use coupon code in this case. If  you dont use coupon code the customer will directly get the discount once he/she enter the shipping address

Comment: Yes, thanks Dexter, I am going to suggest same to my client. Thanks for your effort. Please update your answer, i will mark it as a answer :-)

Comment: Thank you, i have updated my answer.. Hope it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

problem is when the user is not logged in, the system doesnt have any information about the guest, hence also no information about the shipping country -> rule doesnt work.

hope i could help you with my answer.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! But how can i override this? Is tr is any solution for this......